# Distribution of quadratic forms of normal variables

Tags: distributions, self-study

Suppose $X\sim \bf{N}_m(\bf{\mu}, \bf{\Sigma})$ where the covariance matrix $\bf \Sigma$ is positive definite. Show that the distribution of $X^T{\bf{B}}X \sim \chi^2(\bf{tr(B\Sigma)})$where $\bf B$ satisfies

1. $\bf{B\Sigma B}=\bf{B}$
2. $\bf\mu^TB\mu=0$

   Now, previously I had done this result, when $\Sigma$ was replaced by $\bf{I}$ and $B$ was idempotent. This one is where I am stuck. I have found that $\bf B\Sigma$ and $\bf \Sigma B$ are idempotent. Now, I tried to find some $U\sim \bf{N_{\text{tr}(B\Sigma)}}(0, I)$ such that $U^TU=X^T{\bf{B}}X$ then we would be done, but I can't seem to find such an $U$. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: If this is a homework problem, please add a `self-study` tag.

Comment: You might make some progress with your strategy by writing $\Sigma=TT^\prime$ and considering $T^\prime B T$.

Comment: @whuber I have tried these days to proceed with your idea but nothing has come my way, could you tell me how to do it? Thanks a lot.